# Trying to get a loop to stop once a certain value is reached, but it always carries on 1 step too many

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop

As the title suggests. Looking at the block of code:

```
m = 100
a = -9.8
y0 = 30000
t0 = 0
v0 = 0
dt = 0.01

yAF = np.array([])
yAF = np.append(yAF, y0)

tAF = np.array([])
tAF = np.append(tAF, t0)

speedAF = np.array([])
speedAF = np.append(speedAF, v0)

def dy_dt(t):
    return a * t 

i = 0

while yAF[i] >= 0:
    i = i + 1
    tAF = np.append(tAF, tAF[i-1] + dt)
    speedAF = np.append(speedAF, dy_dt(tAF[i-1]))
    yAF = np.append(yAF, yAF[i-1] + dt * dy_dt(tAF[i-1]))
```

As you can see, the condition I am trying to achieve is that when the value yAF[i] goes below zero, I dont want to add it to the array and I want the loop to end.

The code currently still adds the first value less than 0 onto the array before stopping. Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Please add the initializing code. `yAF[i]` on the first line is undefined (and so is `i`).

Comment: `np.append` in a loop is very inefficient (it always is). Append to a list and convert to an array after the loop.

Comment: What else do you expect?  You are testing the last thing in the list.  It's like trying to stop gambling right before you loose money.  You either have to look ahead, or be able to backtrack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inverted the order of checking and appending. You should first check and only then append:

```
yAF, yAF, speedAF = [], [], []
yAF_next, tAF_next, speedFA_next = y0, t0, v0

while yAF_next >= 0:
    yAF.append(yAF_next)
    tAF.append(t0_next)
    speedAF.append(speedFA_next)

    tAF_next = tAF[-1] + dt
    speedAF_next = dy_dt(tAF[-1])
    yAF_next = yAF[-1] + dt * dy_dt(tAF[-1])
```

Interestingly, you do not even need the `i` variable. And yes, work with lists, later convert them to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the while condition to `> 0` instead of `>= 0` to save yourself one loop.

Also, just looking at this code this would give an infinite loop because you're incrementing i but exiting when i is less than 0.

Comment: I've now added more code to make the problem clearer